# Finding a specific position on a slide where a bar in a chart ends

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have specific company requests that require me to add a line to the end of every bar. This line must be an object line outside of the graph, and I must do it for every graph. They want the line to be there before animating, they want it to be on every chart on the slide before any data is shown so the only option is having it as an object.

Is there a way to automate this?

I'm thinking something that finds the position on the chart where the the bar ends, then finding that position relative to the slide and creating a line that is the width of the bar that is placed on that position.

I'm not sure if this can be done, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is an example to help convey my question.

[image: Green bars need added]

Comment: Perhaps an example would be helpful in conveying your question.

Comment: @ashleedawg done, hope it helps understand my question.

Comment: "They want it to be on every chart before any data is shown" - meaning it's a blank chart with just the lines showing? Or just lines floating in space?

Comment: @BigBen a blank chart with lines floating in space. So on one slide I could have 5 different blank charts with lines showing.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to find the last used cell in a range.  Here are several options to do just that.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()
'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Using Find Function (Provided by Bob Ulmas)
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Using SpecialCells Function
  LastRow = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

And...you can find the last used column using these methodologies...

```
Sub FindingLastColumn()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last column number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(7, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

'Using Table Range
  LastColumn = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastColumn = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Columns.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Right (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

End Sub
```

Post back if you have additional questions.